# How can I get the number of branch and cut nodes explored within the script?

Tags: python, docplex

How can I get the number of branch and cut nodes explored within the script? I am using python docplex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `solve details` info contained in `Model.solve_details`. More precisely:

```
  nb_nodes = mdl.solve_details.nb_nodes_processed
```

See http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.sdetails.html#docplex.mp.sdetails.SolveDetails.nb_nodes_processed

Comment: Many thanks, Philipe, you don´t know how much time I spent trying to find this out.

Comment: You're welcome, I'll try to improve the doc. Would you consider flagging the answer as "useful" for other users? Thxs